# C++ Code formatting

Tags: formatting

i have read a lot and for a long time in your great forum. Now this is my first question. I included C++ Code in my latex document and I formatted it successfully. But one detail isn't working. I want to highlite the include statements with the brackets **#include<**graphics.h**>** and **#include<**cmath.h**>** the predefined color MyMoreK and the trigonometric functions with the brackets **sin(**angle**)** and **cos(**angle**)** with the predefined color MyTrigoFunctions. The content of the brackets [graphics.h/cmath.h/angle] should be left in green. 
I tried it for some days now but i couldn't get it to work. I hope you can help me! Thanx a lot for your help and advice!

Same in german: http://golatex.de/cundund-code-wie-kann-ich-noch-einzelne-worte-hervorheben-t18862.html

Best regards, Spliffer

```
    \documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[sfdefault]{AlegreyaSans}
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{listings}
    \definecolor{MyString}{RGB}{101,138,186}
    \definecolor{MyKeyword}{RGB}{0,0,128}
    \definecolor{MyBackground}{RGB}{235,235,235}
    \definecolor{MyIdentifier}{RGB}{0,128,128}
    \definecolor{MyMoreK}{RGB}{49,128,255}
    \definecolor{MyTrigoFunctions}{RGB}{217,87,22}

    \lstset{
    %language=C++,
    %upquote=true,
    %columns=fixed,
    belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
    breaklines=true,
    backgroundcolor=\color{MyBackground},
    %frame=L,
    xleftmargin=\parindent,
    showstringspaces=false,
    basicstyle=\small,
    breakatwhitespace=true,        
    breaklines=true,                
    keepspaces=false,          
    rulecolor=\color{black},
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{MyKeyword},
    stringstyle=\bfseries\color{MyString},
    commentstyle=\color{purple!80!black},%\itshape  
    identifierstyle=\color{MyIdentifier},%\bfseries
    %prebreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},  
    tabsize=1,  
    showtabs=false,
    emph={include},
    emphstyle={\color{MyMoreK}}
    }  
    %\lstset{style=MyCppStyle}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=C++, caption={C++ code using listings}]

//#include<winbgim.h>


int SCREEN_W = 800;
int SCREEN_H = 200;


main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
initwindow(SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H);

setbkcolor(0);
cleardevice();

// Koordinaten für Kreis
int x, y;
const float  PI = 3.14159265358979f;
int length = 50;
float angle = 0.0;
float angle_stepsize = 0.1;

setcolor(15);
settextstyle(10, HORIZ_DIR, 2);

outtextxy(120, 20, "Circle_001 Kreis mit Sinus() und Cosinus(): ");

// go through all angles from 0 to 2 * PI radians
while (angle < 2 * PI)
{
// calculate x, y from a vector with known length and angle
x = length * cos (angle);
y = length * sin (angle);

putpixel((x + SCREEN_W/ 2) - 20 , (y + SCREEN_H/ 2) + 20 ,15);
angle += angle_stepsize;
}

while(!kbhit())
{
delay(1);
}

return 0;
}

\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The minted package should do that fairly easily, but I'm not sure I understand your request: 1) There's no `#include<**graphics.h>**` in the code you want to include in your LaTex document. 2) Could you make your example minimal, i.e., including only what's relevant to your question?